# What is the difference between Model.findOne() & Model.findById() in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, objectid

Consider we are searching a document from MongoDB based on the _id value. Which one of the following code is efficient ?

1. `ModelObj.findById(IdValue).exec(callback);`
2. `ModelObj.findOne({ '_id': IdValue}).exec(callback);`

I feel ModelObj.findById() is efficient, but what are the supportive reasons or How is it efficient?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`findById` is just a convenience function that does exactly the same thing as the `findOne` call you show.

Here's [the source](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/8cb0e355f75140bd4506a80b21dd94244f828cb0/lib/model.js#L1067-L1069):

```
Model.findById = function findById (id, fields, options, callback) {
  return this.findOne({ _id: id }, fields, options, callback);
};
```

Comment: I was thinking/hoping that it would actually consume less computing power since it is finding by Id. But no :)

Answer (score 30):

`findById(id)` is almost equivalent to `findOne({ _id: id })`.
If you want to query by a document's _id, use `findById()` instead of `findOne()`.

Both functions trigger `findOne()`, the only difference is how they treat `undefined`.
If you use `findOne()`, you'll see that `findOne(undefined)` and `findOne({ _id: undefined })` are equivalent to `findOne({})` and return arbitrary documents.
However, mongoose translates `findById(undefined)` into `findOne({ _id: null })`.

See https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById

Here's the [source](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/lib/model.js#L1757-L1767):

```
Model.findById = function findById(id, projection, options, callback) {
  if (typeof id === 'undefined') {
    id = null;
  }

  if (callback) {
    callback = this.$wrapCallback(callback);
  }

  return this.findOne({_id: id}, projection, options, callback);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

findById(id) is just syntactic sugar of the find({_id : id}) or findOne({_id: id})

Answer (score -3):

Using .findOne makes the database look through its records checking each bson document to find the relevant variable and then check the value, if mongo knows its looking for the internally indexed _id field it doesn't have to look through each document

Comment: As pointed by JohnnyHK, it does the exact same thing under the hood